# posting password and username in angular js

Tags: angularjs

While posting password and username to server,it shows in the browser's console window.Here shows the example:

```
POST http://url/chkSignInCustomer 200 OK 306ms
    Post:
    {"cust_email":"abc@gmail.com","cust_login_password":"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"}
```

But I didn't write console.log,How can I avoid this security issue?

Comment: password showed up in the console or network tab?  Also please show your code where you are making the post request.

Comment: In the console.

Comment: can you show your login request code please?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this quite a security issue, because this information is available through the dev tools anyway, even if it isn't logged. And the password was provided by the user anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not writing your request to console.log and also make sure you are not using any type of automatic log.

If you do not want your password to show raw in the network tab > request > payload or even in your console window, You can use crypto.js  or any other encryption library in your front-end.  Understand that depending on the method you use, you password will still not be so secure.

Another thing I recommend depending on the application needs is using https for communications with the server.